# Length measurement along a B-spline

Tags: algorithm, spline

I'm currently working with paths defined on base of a unique B-spline. The B-spline is given by a set of control points and knot values. The number of control points and knots may vary (and remain coherent).

Using the De Boor's algorithm, I am able to evaluate positions on the curve and to get the tangent value for those positions.
So far so good.

Now how to measure (/approximate) arc length along the B-spline path ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve] .. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered

Comment: De Boor makes things simple, but will omit any information about the curve itself other than what it gives. If you really need some analytical way instead of using Codor's answer (which will work just fine in every real world application), you'd actually need to compute the base functions and then use analytical curve integration over each polynomial segment.

Comment: yes, you'd need to compute a definite integral from t=t_start to t=t_end of |d point(t) / dt| dt

Comment: Thanks. Actually I attempt to get something easier than getting the parametric equations to evaluate the spline information. That's why I am using the De Boor's algorithm. I hoped to find a special property of any algo to get a good approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Numerically, it could be done by generating some equidistant points alog the spline, measure the [Euclidean distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between them and sum up these distances. The more points are used, the more accurate the approximation will be.

Comment: I don't think they need to be equidistant, although that would probably get you the most accurate answer for a given number of points.  E.g. it ought to be enough to repeatedly pick the pair of adjacent points whose Euclidean distance is maximum, and create a new point whose parameter value is halfway between them (TTBOMK this in general *won't* put the new point at an equal distance along the curve from the other two).

Comment: Indeed, I did it. It's quite heavy if I wish a minimal accuracy. (Again) I hoped to find a special property of any algo to get a good approximation.

Answer (score 1):

The [arc-length of a parametric curve](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArcLength.aspx) is

```
 ⌠₁ ________________
 ⎮ √ dx(t)² + dy(t)² dt
 ⌡₀
```

Or, integral of the length of its tangents over the whole curve.
For t <- (0, 1); the uniform parametrisation.

First you need to convert the bspline curve to a composite bezier spline.
This is done by inserting "knots" (Boehm's algorithm)
http://www.infogoaround.org/JBook/bstobez.html

For bezier curves, we can calculate the tangent at every point very easily.
And use a numerical integration algorithm, such as [Gauss-Legendre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Gauss.E2.80.93Legendre_quadrature) to integrate the length of the tangent.

Here is a [demo in javasript](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) using code from [paper.js](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js) library.

> Please note that the algorithm is very accurate (within the realm of floating point math, the wikipedia link above has a better example). 
>   Since N point Gauss–Legendre quadrature is exact for a polynomial of degree 2N–1.
>   The magnitude of error in the demo is largely due to the fact that circles cannot be represented as uniform bezier curves exactly, so our curves are just an approximation to begin with.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sounds interesting. I will digest and test this. I will come back to this for reaction. Thanks again.

Comment: @hkrish Completely unrelated to the question: How did you make the unicode formula? Would love to present equations in code comments like this...

Comment: @sonovice Python sympy is one way to do it. First import and init the session with `from sympy import init_session; init_session()`. Then, if you're using ipython, you can just enter the term `integrate(sqrt(diff(f(t), t)**2 + diff(g(t), t)**2), (t, 0, 1))` to have it pretty-printed in the REPL. Without ipython you have to pretty-print it explicitly: `pretty_print(integrate(sqrt(diff(f(t), t)**2 + diff(g(t), t)**2), (t, 0, 1)))` - I used `f(t)` and `g(t)` because `init_session()` pre-initializes those symbols as functions. You can get your own function symbols for `x` and `y` if necessary.